# How to light a scene when you have a sun lamp?

Tags: lighting

I'm trying to light the interior of a room, but the outside is being lit by a sun lamp. It seems like everything inside the room is not lighting up due to the sun lamp. How do I fix this?[image]

Comment: If i understand correctly your interior is too dark?

Comment: Yes, I will post a picture.

Comment: and what exactly are you trying to achieve? In the picture it looks like the interior is light enough. Do you want it even brighter? Or do you want the outside to be dark?

Comment: I want to make the interior brighter.

Comment: then set the stregth of the sun lamp to higher value

Comment: Yes, but that would affect the outside environment. I just want to make the interior brighter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77347/discussion-between-johan-apes-and-opaque-dragon).

Comment: is this for Cycles? I am not sure how your glass shader is set up for the dome but I would set it up this way https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107018/which-glass-shader-is-physically-correct