# HDRI background image won't show behind glass and artificial area light

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, glass

i have an interior scene replicated from photo reference as a way to practise blender.

this scene has sun, artificial area lights to help lighting the interior. and a HDR image to get something as a background and not to light the scene.

i don't know how these work up in Blender and Cycles.

as in SketchUp with other render engines, the background would still show up and visible to the camera. even with rectangular lights added behind the window's glasses to help the interior lighting from the exterior.

[image: scene replicated from photo ref with fspy in blender 2.79]

[image]

Edit:

for now i've come to conclusion that the problem is the glass shader i used. adopted from blenderguru tutorial on kitchen modelling. checked out the Material-Preview and got almost diffused shader. then, i look for different approach for the glass.

i've come to these pages/queries;

[How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)

[Which glass shader is physically correct?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107018/which-glass-shader-is-physically-correct)

[How can I make a more realistic glass shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader)

which suggested "tricky glass" nodes setup material and got strange look at the window in the corner.

[image: trickglass error]

Comment: it seems to work, are you sure your windows are transparent?

Comment: @moonboots, really? from the scene? have you tried to see and render the scene from the fspy's camera? i don't see anything beyond the glasses of the window. but that glowing light on the windows.
i've tried to use the glass material from chocofur and this one with the architectural glass hack material from Andrew Price.
did you see that there are "area lights" in front of those glasses outside?

Comment: have you tried to remove the windows to see if it could come from that?

Comment: also, the World's Background Strength is very high (15), maybe decrease it at 1?

Comment: i've already tried with strength at 1. it was started at that value by default, right? 
haven't tried to remove the windows -or, is it the glasses?- i'll check that then.

Comment: May be the number of bounces of light is too low?